# Deep Reinforcement Learning for time delayed learned environment configuration

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

A model chooses actions in a configured environment for each time step. This changes the environments state.
(state t) -> (state t+1)

A second model can alter the configuration of the environment for the next timestep.
This does not alter the state, but has an effect on the overall reward.
(state t) -> (configuration t+1)

(state, configuration) -> reward

The configuration is a non-linear function selecting a continuous outcome for every event happening in the environment. Thus combining both models with a categorical configuration output is not possible.

How can I train this configuration, since both models depend on each other?
Is it possible with other ideas to integrate both models into one?
Have similar problems already been explored?

My current idea:
Implement both models with PPO2 from stable_baselines.
Freeze model2 for x epochs to allow model1 to improve and prevent oscillation.
Both models will receive the same reward.
Does it make sense to alternate freezing (freeze 2, train 1; freeze 1, train2)?

Comment: Are the two models' rewards tied together or are they working against each other?

Comment: They are tied together, both networks should try to increase the overall reward